Norm density of evaluation functionals in the space of weak$^*$ continuous multilinear functionals on products of dual Banach spaces
Let $K$ be a compact (metrizable) space and let $C(K)$ be the Banach space of continuous real-valued functions on $K$, equipped with the supremum norm. It is then well known that the dual space $C(K)^*$ coincides with finite Borel measures on $K$ and moreover, that the span of evaluation functionals (i.e. finite linear combinations of Dirac measures) is in general not norm-dense in $C(K)^*$.
The most general question is the following (I describe a more concrete problem below). Are there any (non-trivial) sufficient conditions known for a closed subspace $X\subset C(K)$ to have the property that the span of evaluation functionals is norm-dense in $X^*$?
An interesting case in which this holds is the following. Suppose $X$ is a Banach space and $B_{X^*}$ is the unit ball of $X^*$ equipped with the weak$^*$ topology. Then after canonically identifying $X$ with the subspace of $X^{**}$, we have $X\subset C(B_{X^*})$. But now for any $\varphi \in X^*$ and any $x\in X$ we have
$$
\varphi(x)=\|\varphi\|x\left(\frac{\varphi}{\|\varphi\|}\right).
$$ In other words, $\varphi$ itself is an evaluation functional times a scalar.
Note that by unpacking definitions and using the Krein-Smuljan Theorem [1], one can verify that if $X$ is separable, then $X$ coincides with the space of those linear functionals on $X^*$, whose restriction to $B_{X^*}$ is continuous$^1$. I am interested in a multilinear version of this idea.
In the following paragraph I describe the two-linear version.
Suppose $X_1$, $X_2$ are separable Banach spaces and $K=B_{X_1^*}\times B_{X_2^*}$ (equipped with the product of the weak$^*$ topologies). Let $M$ stand for the space of two-linear functionals on $X_1^*\times X_2^*$, whose restrictions to $K$ are continuous. We view $M$ as a subspace of $C(K)$, it can be verified that $M$ is closed. Is it then the case that the span of evaluation functionals is dense in $M^*$? Explicitly, if I am not mistaken, this should be equivalent to the fact that every continuous linear functional $\varphi$ on $M$ is of the form
$$\varphi(T)=\sum_i \lambda_i T(f_i,g_i), \quad \text{for all $T\in M$},$$
where $(f_i,g_i)\in K$, $\sum_i \|f_i\|\|g_i\|<\infty$ and finally
$\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$.
$^1$ It follows from the definitions that $X$, when viewed as a subspace of $X^{**}$, coincides with the space of those linear functionals on $X^*$ which are continuous with respect to the weak$^*$-topology. If $X$ is separable, one can use the Krein-Smuljan theorem [1] to assert that any linear functional on $X^*$ is continuous with respect to the weak$^*$-topology if and only if it is sequentially continuous. However, by the uniform boundedness principle, every weak$^*$-convergent sequence is bounded, and hence it is sufficient to test the continuity on $B_{X^*}$.
[1] John B. Conway, A course in functional Analysis, Corollary 12.8. on page 161

That every linear functional $\varphi:X^\to\mathbb K$ whose restriction to the unit ball $B_{X^}$ is $\sigma(X^*,X)$ continuous is an evaluation has nothing to do with Krein-Smuljan but is a consequence of the completeness of $X$ (a version of such a description of the compeletion holds for general locally convex spaces and is due to Grothendieck).
